# How to re-use variable

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt

This is my code in PyQt5:

```
    def path(self, Interface):
        p= str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self.pathTab1, 'Directory Path','', QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly))
        return (p)

    def enableBox(self, Interface, p):
        if p!= '':
            self.chkDedensification.setCheckable(True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ui.enableBox(Interface, ??????)
```

In the `__name__=="__main__"`, where the `???????` are, I want/have to use 'p', but if I just type `p`, it says that it's not defined. I have the choice to write `p='something'`, but I don't know what that something should be....

I don't understand the reason.

Comment: you could use `global` before changing it in local scopes, but you shouldn't.

Comment: according to your sample you need `ui.enableBox(Interface, path(Interface))` or `p = path(Interface)` and on next line `ui.enableBox(Interface, p)`?

Comment: @ReutSharabani why shouldnt I use global ?
EDIT : even with global it doesnt work.. ??

Comment: @Reishin this doesn't work :/

Comment: @guy16 you is sure about indentation for "def path" ? He is defined in the same way like in the sample ?

Comment: You should fix your indentation. The code as shown is currently broken `def path` is at the same level as `p=`.

Comment: @Reishin indentation is good in my script, it's just a bad copy/paste here

Comment: then try to fix you sample, if path is member of a class, then you should add `ui.` before `path` in my answers. During creating of question you need to carefully read the instructions about code publishing, especially for python

Comment: @Reishin i know, it's a small mistake, i didnt do it on purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `path` which returns `p`.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ui.enableBox(Interface, ui.path(Interface))
```